# Messed up root permissions Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo, display-manager

While changing a directory ownership, accidentally I did

`sudo chown subhadip /`  instead of  `sudo chown MyApp`

After realizing my mistake, tried to fixed few permissions i.e.,  `sudo`  etc. by  `sudo chown -R root /`  stopped operation as its wrong.

Now I am getting *“The system is running in low-graphics mode”* error, which I believe because of wrong permissions only.

I am able to login in console mode.

Please guide me.

Comment: Quite honestly- unless you want to do some searching, comparing and restoring original ownership on files in your system - preserve the necessary files somewhere and rebuild the system. In most cases it will be root - but some system files may have different ownership.

Comment: Thanks, but reinstall is not an option for me...

Comment: @digiwizkid gg, reinstall, unless you want to specifically trawl through all the necessary files in your system and reapply proper permissions to each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repair your personal space, run:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/
```

For any of the other applications that are broken you will have to repair them as you see a problem with an app.  Most of the sysem files are owned by root and most will still work.

Certain services such as `Mysql` and `Apache` are owned by a specific user... in the case of `Mysql` the user is `mysql`.  In the case of `Apache` the default user is `www-data`.

There are other server programs you might run such as `Ftp`.  The `Ftp` server default user is `ftp`.

If an application is broken, it'll most likely give an error that suggests a problem with permission.

Comment: Used GDM for startup fix, will manually fix permission issues on the go.